# Can we come up with a better tag for "Where do I post this?" questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

We've gone through a few phases of tags when it comes to tagging questions about where things should be posted. It's a core aspect of Meta Stack Overflow, especially post-Area 51.

- [where-to-post](/questions/tagged/where-to-post) was the first one. Decent, straight, and to the point. But kinda awkward when you put it alongside the majority of tags here.
- [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) was also used, and I even proposed it in the pre-synonym thread. Back at the time, the two were basically equivalent because we only had the Trilogy - these were implicitly more about the scope of the sites and Meta covered all 3 in the first place. It has faded from use because it no longer properly illustrates this category of questions.
- [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) is what we currently use. Since we now have all of the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites, now things are more about some manner of site directory through Meta Stack Overflow. Focusing on where to post, rather than the actual matter of scope, became more important as scope is more discussed on the individual sites.

On the one hand, "site-rec" is accurate - people need to know what site a question gets posted on, and we post our recommendations. We also have a tag wiki that explains what it means. But knowing what the tag means is worthless if you can't find it in the first place.

The "rec" tag class is entirely non-intuitive to question askers - which is actually intentional as a method to discourage the more aggravating kinds of recommendations being asked. We already have a problem that not all site guidance questions are properly tagged, but with such an obscure tag it simply agitates the issue that new users won't find existing questions that may be on the same subject. An innocent mistake, but something we can fix. As well, the unusual tag also makes it incredibly unlikely that incoming questions will be pre-loaded with the tag, so it has to be manually added every time.

I think a new tag will help a lot here. Something that not only captures the essence of our utility as a site directory, but is also intuitive to new users. It's not going to clean up all of the work in maintenance, but at least it'll turn the tag into something that's useful to more than just the regular Meta denizens who know of its existence.

Comment: What's wrong with **`[where-to-post]`**?  I think that one is the most clear.

Comment: @Justin Nothing's wrong with it - it may even be the best tag right now. But currently, it's an accepted synonym of **[allowed-topics]**, which does kinda block its usage.

Comment: Aw, c'mon! I'm nine questions away from Taxonomist! __Minus one!__

Comment: @Popular You could just create the new tag yourself - then you'll still get Taxonomist without even losing a beat. ♪ If your proposal is good, too, you can even earn yourself a silver **[discussion]** badge from here at the same time.

Comment: I sort of like `lost-in-the-wilderness'. Unless it's on outdoorsman.stackexchange.com. Then it might be misconstrued.

Answer (score 4):

Years later, and the community has adopted [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) for this. It's currently the 20th most popular tag, with 2,441 questions (and counting).

Answer (score 3):

I originally proposed the [where-to-post](/questions/tagged/where-to-post) --> [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) synonym, the latter of which came first IIRC, then [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) popped up later.

I don't think there's any doubt that [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) is a synonym of [where-to-post](/questions/tagged/where-to-post). The only reason it was created is because [where-to-post](/questions/tagged/where-to-post) was involved in the synonym.

Anyway, the reason I even proposed the synonym in the first place was this: people would always ask questions like "should I ask xyz on Stack Overflow?" -- alright, so it's an allowed topic question. Or is it? Every one of those types of questions always implicitly asks a second question as well: "if not Stack Overflow, then where should I post it?". So what type of question is it? Should both tags be used? To me, that seemed like splitting hairs.

I agree that having [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics) show up on every one of these questions isn't great, but neither is having [where-to-post](/questions/tagged/where-to-post) on all of them (maybe it's *better*?).

My main point is that I think these questions should be grouped together somehow, which will help people find them in the future. If we can come up with a tag that encompasses both of these ideas, that would be ideal.

**EDIT:** How about [site-topics](/questions/tagged/site-topics)?

Comment: Conceptually, I agree that scope questions and 'where to post' fit together. But I'm a bit at odds with [site-topics] for the same reason that I'm at odds for keeping [allowed-topics] as the main tag for both scenarios. Meta Stack Overflow is no longer the place to ask about topic acceptability of every site, but those tags would imply otherwise in their phrasing. Pedantry on my part, maybe.

Comment: @Grace: As I said, I would support switching to `[where-to-post]` (I think I would have picked that as the master tag, but it had less questions than `[allowed-topics]`). What I'm wondering is: if MSO is not the place to ask these questions, then where?

Comment: I believe that Meta Stack Overflow is the place to ask these "Is there a site for X" questions. What makes this whole situation tricky is that apart from Stack Overflow, actual *discussion* of the scope of the sites is not on-topic here. You could ask "Does X belong on Y?", but not "Should X belong on Y?" because that belongs on the per-site-meta rather than just noising it up here. Back when we *could* cover the latter, I favored [allowed-topics] and probably even upvoted your synonym. But now, it's a very tricky situation.

Comment: @Grace: Hmmm... Even "does X belong on Y?" sounds like the domain of a per-site meta. Hypothetically, let's say we get every one of these questions (not SO-related) migrated away to the proper per-site Meta. On *this* Meta, it might make sense to break the synonym -- anything with `[allowed-topics]` would be SO-specific, and `[where-to-post]` (or something else) would be used for the "is there a site for X" questions.

Answer (score 1):

[plz-send-teh-webzsitez](/questions/tagged/plz-send-teh-webzsitez)

Answer (score -2):

[find-a-site](/questions/tagged/find-a-site)
[find-me-a-site](/questions/tagged/find-me-a-site)
[find-me-a-se-site](/questions/tagged/find-me-a-se-site)
[find-the-right-site](/questions/tagged/find-the-right-site)
[find-the-right-se-site](/questions/tagged/find-the-right-se-site)
[find-me-the-right-site](/questions/tagged/find-me-the-right-site)
[find-me-the-right-se-site](/questions/tagged/find-me-the-right-se-site)