# Is there a tool to help find where the best place to ask a question is?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-recommendation

My motivation: I wasn't sure where to ask a question about the GnuGPG tool - should it be Stack Overflow, or Server Fault, or Super User?

Ultimately, I decided by searching for "GPG" on the three sites and seeing which had the most questions with the highest votes.

Could a tool help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool is your fellow users; just ask here, and use the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag. ([Until we come up with a better tag.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76740/can-we-come-up-with-a-better-tag-for-where-do-i-post-this-questions))

In response to Alan's comment:
We are definitely quick to close/migrate here, and I know the default comment that gets inserted isn't exactly worded in the friendliest way possible. That said, I fully support aggressive closure/migration, because everyone benefits when related information is tied together. If the OP looks like a new user, some of us leave courtesy comments explaining what's happening, and why, and that it's not a negative thing.

As for a "not sure where to post?" link that points here: I think that's unnecessary. If you ask the question on a "regular" site, and you don't pick the site completely at random from all SE sites, it has a decent chance of being in the right place. On MSO, it's almost certainly **not** in the right place, *and* migrating things out of here is hard.

I hope that addresses your concern, I'm not 100% sure I understood your intent. Feel free to leave another comment if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

A highly effective tool is thorough use of search engines: if you use the site:stackexchange.com filter and search for a specific field, you will find whichever questions have previously been discussed here for the same topic, and which forums they are most debated on.

[site:stackexchange.com clips](http://site:stackexchange.com%20clips)