# Should where-to-post be merged with site-rec?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we come up with a better tag for “Where do I post this?” questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76740/can-we-come-up-with-a-better-tag-for-where-do-i-post-this-questions)

[where-to-post](/questions/tagged/where-to-post) is a synomn of [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics).   Neither have a tag wiki.

However [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) has a tag wiki of

> Don't know where to ask your question
>   on the Stack Exchange Network? This
>   tag denotes a question asking where it
>   is best to ask a particular kind or
>   topic of question.

Looks like [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) needs to be synonym of [allowed-topics](/questions/tagged/allowed-topics), or [where-to-post](/questions/tagged/where-to-post) needs to by a synonym of [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec).  Or maybe even some third solution.

Comment: Related [discussion on the subject](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76740/can-we-come-up-with-a-better-tag-for-where-do-i-post-this-questions), if not the super-discussion for it. There's a bit of an issue with Meta Stack Overflow's dual purpose which makes there be two different cases of "allowed topics" that it works with.